# Why use AWS machine learning?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, regression, aws-sdk

I'm doing a multiple linear regression. I got about 100 different independent variables (IV) and 1 dependent variable (DV). The IV can be binary, categorical or numerical - no text here. The DV is numerical.

What is the advantage of creating this model through **Amazon** and their machine learning algorithms vs just solving the model using normal statistics methods myself?

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can solve this on your local machine using statistics (R, Python, or the suite of your choice).  Nothing stops you from doing so.

One dependent variable and hundreds of independent variables are easily within reach of a single desktop machine.  It sounds like you need a generalized linear model.

I have a six core AMD machine with 32GB of RAM at home.  I'm certain that I could solve your problem without having to wait too long.

Your bigger issue might be data cleansing, preparation, and deciding which of those 100 independent variables are meaningful.  You'll want to check them to make sure they aren't correlated.  Maybe a PCA or lasso technique could help you winnow them down to the most significant set.

You don't say how many rows you have in your data set.  I'd say you're safe even with millions of rows.

I don't see anything in your use case to suggest that neural networks should be your first choice.

I would run machine learning algorithms on AWS if I had a neural network model with lots of neurons (millions or billions) that required the kind of distributed computing power that I could only get from Amazon.  I'd be prepared to get my credit card out and pay for the privilege, but the option would be available to me if I needed it.

Comment: With all due respect, the 1E6+ ANN example is rather a professional anti-pattern for going into clouds, as it is exactly the business-model that never adjusts the ( many added ( avoidable ) costs -- both directly paid in money and also indirectly ( paid again in money, but by new excessive execution times, introduced by a principally poor scaling ) -- arising from a poor "inter-neural" propagation latency ( if one is to name just a major one ). Supporting cloud-operator business-model is possible, but neither wise, nor enterpreneurial. Investing in own infrastructure has infinitely better ROI.

Comment: No disrespect taken.  I don't think my answer is recommending any anti-patterns or bad use of cloud.  I will disagree with this statement: "Supporting cloud-operator business-model is possible, but neither wise, nor enterpreneurial. Investing in own infrastructure has infinitely better ROI."  Every start up that is flocking to AWS precisely because they don't have to invest in infrastructure says you are wrong.

Comment: Right, have seen many hubs that sponsor going into cloud, by vouchers or VC-pre-paid cloud-quotas. But, **this does not mean it is wise to base the IP/alpha on a foreign-service** platform, but it is a mean incentive not to invest in due time. Any business-entity, that cannot invest in it's own facilities, be it mature or startup, is destined to become totally dependent on such service-provisioning (thus principally extrinsic risks of changes in ownership, of inappropriate scaling costs, DoS & inammortizable costs of learning curves are just few issues never had with private infrastructure ).

Comment: "Naive Cloudy" Projects, that turn out in having such immense OPEX costs, that would just **in first 9 months cover a CAPEX + y/y OPEX costs** of a much better & much higher performance on a privately owned + operated infrastructure are the best examples, to **show how bad business anti-pattern the Cloudy-promises could go**. With your experience, you could easily imagine additional costs of scaling up cloud-contracts. Except for marketing drums and whistles, I would like to see an audited business-cases, where cloud OPEX-60 would be lower than a TCO-60 of the private infrastructure.

Comment: FYI AWS do not do neural networks. It's linear, logistic or multivariate logistic.

Comment: FYI AWS does make Tensorflow available: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01EYKBEQ0